# Synchronize a set of table records via triggers

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have a table from an existing product (so no schema changes are possible) that have a schema similar to the following:

```
objectId, typeId, value
```

What I need to do is to essentially make several typeIds linked and in synch with each other. See the example below. There will be around 35 sets of 3-4 linked typeIds each.

I cannot figure out reasonable way to do this that is performant, handles multi-row inserts and prevents trigger recursion. Any suggestions?

## Example

typeId 1, 2 and 3 should be linked.

```
INSERT INTO foo (objectId, typeId, value) VALUES (1, 1, 'bar')
```

Should result in the table containing the following

```
╔══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ objectId ║ typeId ║ value ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║        1 ║      1 ║ bar   ║
║        1 ║      2 ║ bar   ║
║        1 ║      3 ║ bar   ║
╚══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Any updates to the value of either of these records should result in the value of all of them to be changed.

Comment: Can you not change the logic that is creating the insert to insert the desired rows too?

Comment: I was about to say that it is within DLLs that I cannot modify, but I believe there are stored procedures for the actual inserts and updates. I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the SAME table, or in a duplicate table?  I'm finding the question statement confusing.  can you NAME the tables in your example ("A" and "B" if there are two?) and show what BOTH should contain after each insert or update?

Comment: It is in the SAME table. In the end, I managed to accomplish the functionality by modifying the insert and update stored procedures used by the application, as per Dane's suggestion. This does not cover direct database manipulation, but it works well enough for the intended purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved my problem by modifying the "insert" and "update" stored procedures used by the application in question, instead of solving it with triggers.

The insert procedure ended up something like this:

```
IF @typeId IN (1,2,3)
    INSERT INTO foo (objectId, typeId, value) VALUES (@objectId, 1, @value), (@objectId, 2, @value), (@objectId, 3, @value)
ELSE IF 
    ...
ELSE
   INSERT INTO foo (objectId, typeId, value) VALUES (@objectId, @typeId, @value)
```

The update procedure ended up something like this:

```
IF @typeId IN (1,2,3)
    UPDATE foo SET value = @value WHERE objectId = @objectId AND @typeId IN (1,2,3)
ELSE IF
    ...
ELSE
    UPDATE foo SET value = @value WHERE rowId = @rowId
```